# How to delete rows in a pandas dataframe if they contain values from a list?

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Beer            Rating
0   Heineken        Good
1   Budweiser       Bad
2   Coors Light     Bad
```

and a list that looks like this:

```
bad_beers = ["Light", "0.0%"]
```

**How to delete every row in a pandas dataframe that contains a given string from a list?**

The desired output should look like this:

```
    Beer       Rating
0   Heineken   Good
1   Budweiser  Bad
```

Comment: this example has a focus on columns, mine on rows

Comment: I don't think so... the top answer is filtering on rows.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str.contains`

```
df[~df.Beer.str.contains('Light')]
Out[364]: 
        Beer Rating
0   Heineken   Good
1  Budweiser    Bad
```

If list contain more items using | .

```
df[~df.Beer.str.contains('Light|Heineken')]
Out[365]: 
        Beer Rating
1  Budweiser    Bad
```

Comment: What if you want do that for every column? Exclude the 'Beer' does not work. Can you use the same syntax? Or is it better to use a lambda?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer I will recommend apply lambda

Comment: I will raise a question. As I cannot use the col names. I have not defined them in the dataframe.